# Listening for changes in HTMLCollection (or achieving a similar effect)

Tags: javascript, performance, tooltip, watch, mutation-observers

I need to create a simple tooltip library that works like this:

every DOM element with a specific attribute combination (like class="tooltip", data-tooltip-text="some text") automatically displays a tooltip (containing text from data attr) on hover.

This behavior must persist through external DOM manipulation. I really like the idea of utilizing a [HTMLcollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) for this, for its "live" nature, as iterating the whole DOM with every DOM change sounds potentially very demanding.

Now I would love to watch/listen the collection and run a sequence every time it changes (iterate through the nodes, see if they have a listener, add it if they don't).

How do I do this? The [watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) and [observe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) methods seem to (if I understand correctly) be capable of that, but they are now deprecated. MDN says that [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) covers most use cases, but does it cover mine (I haven't found a way to make it work)? Or is there some other way I'm missing?

And what about [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)? I assume that deep-observing the whole application and repeatedly fetching a new NodeList via querySelectorAll with every single change would be too demanding (the library should run over a React application). Dynamically committing the HTMLCollection (as a value) into DOM via React and then (shallowly) listening for changes with MutationObserver might work, but I doubt that would be a good idea either.

Comment: Add a `mouseover` listener on `window` and check event.target.closest('.tooltip, [data-tooltip-text="foo"]'), then show the tooltip if it matched an element. As for MutationObserver approach, you don't need to recheck everything, just the changes, see also [Performance of MutationObserver to detect nodes in entire DOM](//stackoverflow.com/a/39332340)

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried both and it seems that the mousover listener really performs much better in large DOMs. Thank you!