# How to observe an HTMLCollection?

Tags: javascript, dom

A little curious since I know that HTMLCollections update themselves automatically, I tried observing them by using a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) as shown below

```js
let imagesCollection = document.images;

let io = new Proxy(imagesCollection, {
    set: (target, prop, value, reciever) => {
        // do stuff
        // apply default behaviour
        return Reflect.set(target, prop, value);
    }
});

// test the block by adding new elements

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<img>");
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<img class='img'>");
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend",
    "<img class='img' src='https://picsum.photos/200/300'>"
);
```

but when trying to add dynamically some images, nothing happen ...

So my questions are :

- Is that even possible ?
- If yes, Am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: What about using a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, let me check that quickly

Comment: It may not be exactly what you're looking or. What are you trying to solve by observing a collection?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, yeah, [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) do help react with the added element but not with the collection

Comment: i am just looking for a better solution for the lazy-loading of my images and the idea of observation of collections is only intended to satisfy my curiosity since it reduces the field of research and delete the loops found in the MutationObserver's callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, proxies intercept operations with proxies, not with targets:

```js
let target = {};

let proxy = new Proxy(target, {
    set: (target, prop, value, reciever) => {
        console.log(prop, value);
        return Reflect.set(target, prop, value);
    }
});

target.foo = 'I am not intercepted.';
proxy.bar = 'I am intercepted.';
```

So in your case, operations with `io` are intercepted, while operations with `imagesCollection` or `document.images` are not.

So mutation observer is a better option.

Comment: Ooooh, thanks. Your explanation makes my understanding of proxies more clearer. Only the proxies are observed, not the targets. So would it be impossible to directly observe the Collections?
---
Ps: I already know how to observe elements on the DOM by using MutationObserver

Comment: @ntdash Sorry, I cannot think of any way to  directly observe Collections. Maybe someone else has)

Comment: @ntdash Some similar questions seem unanswered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062602/htmlcollection-change-event-with-javascript or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55046093/listening-for-changes-in-htmlcollection-or-achieving-a-similar-effect

Comment: Wooo , they were looking for the same things XD. 
Last question then :
Is the MutationObserver needy in terms of memory or cpu ?

Comment: @ntdash Sorry, I do not know. Maybe it is worth a separate question)

Comment: I see ... Thanks anyway. You made me less stupid. XD ...